# Mount ext2/ext3 in Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, ext3, macfuse

I'm trying to extract files from an ext3 formatted drive.  I have snow leopard.  I have tried the Macfuse/macfusion/fuse-ext2 suggestions but suspect my lack of experience is causing a problem.  I have downloaded each of these three programs and installed them by double clikking pkg installer and following instructions.  However, only macfusion appears in apps and I don't understand what I'm looking at when I open it.  My ext3 formatted drive doesn't appear at all.  Any help or suggestions gratefully received.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This site has a really good tutorial of going about doing this. Sadly you have to do this sort of thing by hand. [Mounting ext2/ext3 via MacFuse](http://ekettoz.blogspot.com/2009/06/mounting-linux-ext2ext3-partitions.html)

That said, all hope is not lost for automation!  At work I have to mount an ssh filesystem all the time. I was able to automate this process with an Automator Script that I saved as an application that I leave on my desktop.  Use Disk Utility to figure out the /dev/name for your drive when you plug it in.

However, because the /dev/name could change if you plug different drives in at the same time, you will probably have to figure out a way to get that drive name from AppleScript (likely) and use it's shell execute stuff.  I'm not very good with AppleScript, so I'm not sure how you'd go about that part of it.